# Java VisualVM (jvisualvm) tool throws warning "could not install some modules" at startup

Tags: java, jvisualvm

Java VisualVM (jvisualvm) tool throws warning "could not install some modules" at startup and doesn't start thereafter even clicking jvisualvm warning screen ignore button.

> System details:
>       1. Java version "1.8.0" Java HotSpot (TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
>           25.0-b69, mixed mode) 
>       2. OS Debian 7.8 64bit

```
Issue Warning details below:
Warning - could not install some modules:
    org.netbeans.lib.profiler.common - None of the modules providing the capability org.netbeans.lib.profiler.common.Profiler could be installed.
    org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api - The module org.netbeans.lib.profiler.common would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.core - The module org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.core - The module org.netbeans.lib.profiler.common would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.core - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler/2 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler.heapwalker was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sa - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sa - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sa - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sa - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sa - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.appui - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.appui - The module org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.core/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler/2 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.application/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler.snaptracer/1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler/2 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler.utilities/1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.core/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module org.netbeans.lib.profiler.common would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named org.netbeans.modules.profiler/2 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.application/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler - The module named com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling/0-1 was needed and not found.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.remote - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.host would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.remote - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.core would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.remote - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.application would also need to be installed.
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.remote - The module com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools would also need to be installed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enabled: org.netbeans.modules.profiler.api
    at org.netbeans.Module.getClassLoader(Module.java:402)
    at org.netbeans.StandardModule.getParentLoader(StandardModule.java:526)
    at org.netbeans.StandardModule.classLoaderUp(StandardModule.java:483)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:1026)
    at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.enable(ModuleManager.java:970)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.installNew(ModuleList.java:301)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleList.trigger(ModuleList.java:237)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.restore(ModuleSystem.java:262)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:142)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Main.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Main.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(TopThreadGroup.java:84)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 2):

Root cause was  jvisualvm user directory pointing to some old java reference which I deleted and corrected. Details as follows:

In order to find out the details of the issue; I ran jvisualvm with console option

```
**./jvisualvm -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true
```

Which gave me some output and details as shown below:

```
Log Session: Monday, August 8, 2016 12:39:55 AM EDT
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = Java VisualVM
  Operating System        = Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.0-b69; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0-b129
  Java Home               = /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_US (visualvm); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /root
  Current Directory       = /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/bin
  User Directory          = /root/.visualvm/7u60
  Cache Directory         = /root/.cache/visualvm/7u60
  Installation            = /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/visualvm
                            /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/profiler
                            /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/classes:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/boot.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/dt.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/core/core.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup_ja.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/local/jetty/common/Java/jdk8/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/core_visualvm.jar
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Everything was fine in terms of jdk8 and home etc. but user directory was pointing to some non existing java path and then I traced it in my linux filesystem:

```
User Directory          = /root/.visualvm/7u60
```

In order to solve the problem; I deleted the `/root/.visualvm/7u60` directory in my OS.
Ran the `./jvisualvm` again and it worked without issue.

Earlier I tried running with `./jvisualvm` with `--help` option where seen the jdkhome and tried for changing the jdkhome but was no luck. Finally removing the folder from the OS worked for me.

```
Wow! Great!!
```